# gradient of function on unit circle

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ : $\mathbb{R^2}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$ be smooth function. Assume that for all $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\left\|(a,b)\right\|=1$ we have $\left \langle (a,b),\nabla f(a,b)\right\rangle=0$. Prove that there is a point $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\left\|(x,y)\right\|=1$ and $\nabla f(x,y)=0$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For $(x,y)$ on the unit circle, $\nabla f(x,y)\cdot(-y,x)$ is the rate of change of $f$ with respect to $\theta$, where $(r,\theta)$ are polar coordinates. If we integrate $\nabla f(x,y)\cdot(-y,x)$ around the unit circle, we get the net change from the start point to the end point. If we integrate around the whole circle, the integral must be $0$. Since $\nabla f(x,y)\cdot(-y,x)$ is smooth with integral of $0$, it must be zero at some point, $(x_0,y_0)$, on the unit circle.

We are given that $\nabla f(x,y)\cdot(x,y)=0$ everywhere on the unit circle.

$\nabla f(x_0,y_0)$ is perpendicular to the two perpendicular vectors $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(-y_0,x_0)$. What does that say?

Comment: I don't understand the part with the integral and the rate of change where can I read about it?

Comment: Since $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, we have $\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}=-r\sin(\theta)=-y$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}=r\cos(\theta)=x$
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}
&=\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\\
&=-y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\\
&=(-y,x)\cdot\nabla f
\end{align}
$$
See [Total Derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) and [Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)

Comment: Suppose $f$ is smooth, $f(0)=f(1)$, and $\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$. Since the integral is $0$, $f$ must be both positive and negative on $[0,1]$ or $0$ everywhere on $[0,1]$. If $f$ is continuous and both positive and negative, it must be $0$ somewhere ([Intermediate Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)).